# Counting the occurrences of ID in a Many to many table Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, many-to-many, compound-key

I am creating a function where my application will show the most liked photos.

I have this class

```
public class User{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserLikedPhoto> likedPhotos = new HashSet<UserLikedPhoto>();
   //Other properties and accessor methods.
}
```

Photo Class

```
public class Photo{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType .LAZY ,mappedBy = "pk.photo")
    private Set<UserLikedTrack> likedByUsers = new HashSet<UserLikedTrack>();
        //Other properties and accessor methods
}
```

The CompoundId/CompoundObject

```
@Embeddable
public class UserLikedPhotoId  implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private UserProfile user;

    @ManyToOne
    private Photo photo;
    //Other Properties and accessor methods.
}
```

And the class that holds the CompoundObject and the date

```
  @Entity
    @AssociationOverrides({
            @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.userId", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId")),
            @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.photoid", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "photoId")) })
    public class UserLikedPhoto{

        @EmbeddedId
        private UserLikedPhotoId pk = new UserLikedPhotoId();
        @Column
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date date;

           //Other Entities and accssor methods
    }
```

With this Class. I'll be generated with this type of table

```
------------------------------
| date |    UserId   photoId |
-----------------------------
| 2010-12-23  | 1   | 23 |
| 2010-12-21  | 2   | 23 |
| 2010-12-23  | 1   | 24 |
| 2010-12-21  | 5   | 23 |
```

Now what I want to do is get the most voted photo (maybe the top 5 or top 10 on a given date) in the example, the most voted photo is photo number 23. and the second most voted is number 24.

In Hibernate how will I make query for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0):

Havent trie this.. but just try... if didnt work i will delete this answer

`select photoId, count(photoId) from UserLikedPhoto group by photoId order by count(photoid) desc`

in this query we are grouping by photoid so there will be only 1 row for 1 photo id.

the count of how many times this photo id available in `UserLikedPhoto` will tell us number of likes of the photo...

we are ordering with desc so one with most like will come at top. 
you asked you want first 5 or 10... so you can use top 10 or top 5 sql clause in select statement

so final sql will be something like this...

`select top 10 photoId, count(photoId) from UserLikedPhoto  group by photoId order by count(photoid) desc`

Hibernate does allow support for native sql too.

Comment: Selec top 10? is there such thing? and I do not want to manually count all of the photos manually. what I want is a query where it will just get the most occurences of a certain ID.

Comment: the 'top' clause seems not to be working. it is giving me an sql syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it's really difficult to get it right from the beginning, but here is my try:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select p from 
    Photo as p, 
    (select ulp.pk.photo.photoId as photoId from UserLikedPhoto ulp 
           where ulp.date = :someDate group by ulp.pk.photo.photoId 
                 order by count(ulp.pk.photo.photoId) desc) as top 
    where p.photoId = top.photoId");
q.setParameter("someDate", new Date())
q.setMaxResults(10);
List<Photo> topPhotos = q.list();
```